# Rust Closure not allowing access to outside data

Tags: rust

I am working on implementing a Shell in Rust. I am using the [ctrlc crate](https://docs.rs/ctrlc/3.1.7/ctrlc/) for handling SIGINT, and my intention is to forward the SIGINT signals received to the process currently running in the shell (the foreground job):

```
mod jobs;


struct KSH {
    jobManager: jobs::JobManager,
}

impl<'a> KSH {
    fn setupSignalHandlers(&'a mut self) {
        ctrlc::set_handler(move || {
            sys::signal::kill(unistd::Pid::from_raw(self.jobManager.getFgJob() as i32), sys::signal::Signal::SIGINT).expect("cannot send ctrl-c")
        })
        .expect("Error setting Ctrl-C handler");
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:55:28
   |
55 |   ...   ctrlc::set_handler(move || {
   |  __________________________^
56 | | ...       let pid = self.jobManager.getFgJob();
57 | | ...       sys::signal::kill(unistd::Pid::from_raw(self.jobManager.getFgJob() as i32), sys::signal::Signal::SIGINT).expect("cannot send ct...
58 | | ...   })
   | |_______^
   |
```

How can I best allow this closure to have an appropriate lifetime so as to be able to access the structs data (the foreground jobs pid in this case)?

Comment: Not a lot of context to go of. But it sounds like this might be a case for using [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) or [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation, `set_handler` requires a `'static` callback, meaning the callback must be able to live forever.

Here your callback includes a reference to `self`, meaning it can't outlive `self` (`'a`), which is definitely not `'static`.

The simplest way to fix this issue is to pass only "owned" data to the callback, e.g.

```rust
mod jobs;


struct KSH {
    jobManager: Arc<jobs::JobManager>,
}

impl<'a> KSH {
    fn setupSignalHandlers(&self) {
        let jobs = Arc::clone(self.jobManager)
        ctrlc::set_handler(move || {
            sys::signal::kill(unistd::Pid::from_raw(jobs.getFgJob() as i32), sys::signal::Signal::SIGINT).expect("cannot send ctrl-c")
        })
        .expect("Error setting Ctrl-C handler");
    }
}
```

as-is, the `JobManager` will be immutable, so you will also need a way to synchronise access e.g. `Mutex` or `RwLock`. And I don't think locking are signal-safe, so that sounds iffy (consider what happens if you receive a signal while the JobManager is locked?). But I've mostly tried to stay the hell away from the madness that is signals so I can't really help you there.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm sorry if this a bad/silly question, but why does immutability necessitate synchronization primitives? Everything is single threaded in this instance.

Comment: @user2489946 In this case, the signal handler may still get invoked asynchronously relative to your code.